# Why do I get the the surface edge closed and how to prevent it?

Tags: plotting

I have a list called "b" and when I use ListPlot3D function to get the surface of the list; the surface's edge is closed as you see in the figüre but I don't want the edge to be closed like that. What could I do to solve this problem ?

```
b={{-0.734936,0.676489,1.00187},{-0.870847,0.828611,0.937642},{-1.01044,0.981459,0.994289},{-1.15373,1.13504,1.08527},{-1.3007,1.28934,1.1864},{-1.45137,1.44437,1.28758},{-0.683079,0.731911,1.36736},{-0.789785,0.91049,1.14136},{-0.904453,1.08576,1.12626},{-1.02708,1.25771,1.18277},{-1.15768,1.42636,1.26898},{-1.29623,1.59169,1.36762},{-0.626413,0.782206,1.73348},{-0.707384,0.982853,1.35911},{-0.799561,1.17684,1.26175},{-0.902943,1.36418,1.27309},{-1.01753,1.54486,1.33582},{-1.14332,1.71889,1.42502},{-0.564939,0.827374,2.05975},{-0.623646,1.0457,1.57316},{-0.695768,1.25472,1.39287},{-0.781307,1.45444,1.3522},{-0.880262,1.64486,1.38479},{-0.992632,1.82597,1.45918},{-0.498657,0.867415,2.32624},{-0.538569,1.09903,1.76808},{-0.593075,1.31939,1.5114},{-0.662176,1.52849,1.41559},{-0.745873,1.72634,1.41346},{-0.844164,1.91293,1.46927},{-0.427568,0.902329,2.52971},{-0.452153,1.14285,1.93258},{-0.491481,1.37085,1.60938},{-0.545551,1.58634,1.45837},{-0.614363,1.78931,1.41924},{-0.697917,1.97977,1.45482},{-0.35167,0.932117,2.67594},{-0.364399,1.17714,2.05958},{-0.390986,1.4091,1.67941},{-0.43143,1.62797,1.47539},{-0.485732,1.83377,1.39974},{-0.553891,2.0265,1.41652},{-0.270964,0.956778,2.77363},{-0.275307,1.20193,2.14511},{-0.29159,1.43413,1.71458},{-0.319815,1.6534,1.46128},{-0.35998,1.85972,1.35333},{-0.412086,2.0531,1.35752},{-0.185451,0.976312,2.83084},{-0.184876,1.21719,2.18647},{-0.193294,1.44596,1.70786},{-0.210705,1.66262,1.41058},{-0.237108,1.86716,1.27994},{-0.272503,2.05959,1.28477},{-0.0951294,0.990719,2.85322},{-0.0931073,1.22295,2.18006},{-0.0960975,1.44458,1.65093},{-0.1041,1.65563,1.31764},{-0.117114,1.85609,1.18199},{-0.135141,2.04596,1.20983},{4.44089*10^-16,1.,2.84303},{4.44089*10^-16,1.21918,2.11871},{4.44089*10^-16,1.42999,1.53214},{4.44089*10^-16,1.63243,1.17654},{4.44089*10^-16,1.8265,1.06519},{4.44089*10^-16,2.0122,1.14791}};
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `closed`? Did you try to rotate the image to see? I do not see it closed at all. Look below it?

Comment: @Nasser How could I remove the pink one ?

Answer (score 7):

It's not all that easy to do. The problem is that `ListPlot3D` doesn't like to follow a concave edge.

```
b =
  {{-0.734936,0.676489,1.00187}
   {-0.870847,0.828611,0.937642}
   {-1.01044,0.981459,0.994289}
   {-1.15373,1.13504,1.08527}
   {-1.3007,1.28934,1.1864}
   {-1.45137,1.44437,1.28758}
   {-0.683079,0.731911,1.36736}
   {-0.789785,0.91049,1.14136}
   {-0.904453,1.08576,1.12626}
   {-1.02708,1.25771,1.18277}
   {-1.15768,1.42636,1.26898}
   {-1.29623,1.59169,1.36762}
   {-0.626413,0.782206,1.73348}
   {-0.707384,0.982853,1.35911}
   {-0.799561,1.17684,1.26175}
   {-0.902943,1.36418,1.27309}
   {-1.01753,1.54486,1.33582}
   {-1.14332,1.71889,1.42502}
   {-0.564939,0.827374,2.05975}
   {-0.623646,1.0457,1.57316}
   {-0.695768,1.25472,1.39287}
   {-0.781307,1.45444,1.3522}
   {-0.880262,1.64486,1.38479}
   {-0.992632,1.82597,1.45918}
   {-0.498657,0.867415,2.32624}
   {-0.538569,1.09903,1.76808}
   {-0.593075,1.31939,1.5114}
   {-0.662176,1.52849,1.41559}
   {-0.745873,1.72634,1.41346}
   {-0.844164,1.91293,1.46927}
   {-0.427568,0.902329,2.52971}
   {-0.452153,1.14285,1.93258}
   {-0.491481,1.37085,1.60938}
   {-0.545551,1.58634,1.45837}
   {-0.614363,1.78931,1.41924}
   {-0.697917,1.97977,1.45482}
   {-0.35167,0.932117,2.67594}
   {-0.364399,1.17714,2.05958}
   {-0.390986,1.4091,1.67941}
   {-0.43143,1.62797,1.47539}
   {-0.485732,1.83377,1.39974}
   {-0.553891,2.0265,1.41652}
   {-0.270964,0.956778,2.77363}
   {-0.275307,1.20193,2.14511}
   {-0.29159,1.43413,1.71458}
   {-0.319815,1.6534,1.46128}
   {-0.35998,1.85972,1.35333}
   {-0.412086,2.0531,1.35752}
   {-0.185451,0.976312,2.83084}
   {-0.184876,1.21719,2.18647}
   {-0.193294,1.44596,1.70786}
   {-0.210705,1.66262,1.41058}
   {-0.237108,1.86716,1.27994}
   {-0.272503,2.05959,1.28477}
   {-0.0951294,0.990719,2.85322}
   {-0.0931073,1.22295,2.18006}
   {-0.0960975,1.44458,1.65093}
   {-0.1041,1.65563,1.31764}
   {-0.117114,1.85609,1.18199}
   {-0.135141,2.04596,1.20983}
   {4.44089*10^-16,1.,2.84303}
   {4.44089*10^-16,1.21918,2.11871}
   {4.44089*10^-16,1.42999,1.53214}
   {4.44089*10^-16,1.63243,1.17654}
   {4.44089*10^-16,1.8265,1.06519}
   {4.44089*10^-16,2.0122,1.14791}};
```

First lets project your data onto the xy-plane.

```
Graphics[Point[b[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]]
```

[image: pts]

This clearly shows a concave edge along the bottom the plot. To get Mathematica to follow this edge in 3D, we will restrict it the region made by fitting poly-lines to the outermost points in the array shown above.

It is useful to break the array into six rows of 11 points each. This makes it easier to extract the points we need for the poly-lines.

```
 b2D = Partition[b[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 6];
```

Here are the expression the make the poly-lines:

```
b2Dlf = Line[First[b2D]];
b2Drt = Line[Last[b2D]];
b2Dbtm = 
  Line[
    With[{f = Interpolation[First /@ b2D]},
      With[{d = First@f["Domain"]}, 
        Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, Subdivide[Sequence @@ d, 23]}]]]];
b2Dtop = Line[Last /@ b2D];
```

`b2Dbtm` is complicated because it is the concave edge where we need to supply more information to Mathematica.

Now we make a region out of the poly-lines.

```
r = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Graphics[{b2Dlf, b2Drt, b2Dbtm, b2Dtop}]]
```

[image: region]

Finally, we use the region to restrict the plot and we also tell Mathematica to plot at a higher resolution than the default setting.

```
ListPlot3D[b,
  MaxPlotPoints -> 100,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y} ∈ r]]
```

[image: surface]

[image: top]

Comment: Thank you very much @m_goldberg. You are great.

Comment: I have a problem that has a warning it says             Table::iterb: "Iterator {x,Subdivide[-0.734936,4.44089*10^-16,23]} does not have appropriate bounds" @m_goldberg

Comment: @user45055. What version of Mathematica are you using? The code that appears in my answer requires Version 10.1 or later.